# FXG ScaleGrid on BitmapImage not working

Tags: apache-flex, bitmapimage, fxg

Does anyone encounter this? FXG ScaleGrid seem to be not working on BitmapImage. Below are my code:

```
<Graphic version="2.0" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008" scaleGridTop="6" scaleGridLeft="6" scaleGridRight="94" scaleGridBottom="54" >


<Rect width="100" height="60" radiusX="4" radiusY="4" >
    <fill>
        <LinearGradient rotation="90" >
            <GradientEntry color="#00649f" />
            <GradientEntry color="#005080" />
        </LinearGradient>
    </fill>
    <stroke>
        <LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" >
            <GradientEntry color="#0079c1" />
            <GradientEntry color="#004b77" />
        </LinearGradientStroke>
    </stroke>               
</Rect>

<!-- Use BitmapImage for InnerGlow, since ScaleGrid will not work on filter -->
<BitmapImage x="0" y="0" source="@Embed('skins/mobi/assets240/InnerGlow240.png')" scaleX="1" scaleY="1" fillMode="scale" width="100" height="60" />


</Graphic>
```

When I scale it, the **Rect** portion has no problem in scaling, but the **BitmapImage** didn't scale according to the scaleGrid set, is there anything that I have done it wrongly?

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 0):

Now I realize that there are many limitions on Scale9Grid, but I found the solution from here: http://old.troygilbert.com/2009/08/quick-fix-for-scale-9-issues/